# Infer dependent variables to produce output aligned to trained data

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, recurrent-neural-networks

Hypothetical example, say I wanted: `P(gender,ethnicity|age,hair)`; so that the input would aligned to a trained dataset of: `(gender,ethnicity,age,hair) => hat bought`.

What approach is 'best' for computing ~gender and ~ethnicity given age,hair; in order to predict the hat bought?

The processing of the `inputs => hat` can be done/learned offline whereas infering the missing input values shall be done online. The results of the online pass shouldn't be stored in the network.

FYI: I am considering two Recurrent Neural Networks one for each problem.

Comment: Hmm, looks like what I'm talking about is called [Imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics))